# Want to add all opportunities into Custom Object(Budget) realted list according to closed date

Tags: apex, trigger

[image]

---

I created a custom object budget which will store company budget for every month. I created opportunity related list into budget and I want to show all opportunities into that related list according to close date.
Let say if any opportunity close date is Jan so it should be show under Jan budget.
How can I achieve this do I need to create trigger to pull all opportunities into budget related list.

Comment: Are you creating a budget for every month?

Comment: Yes. Every month and opportunities who have same month close date should be show under that month budget.

Comment: I did and opportunity related list come under budget but the problem is I want to show all opportunity whos closed date are in jan comes under jan budget and fen come under feb budget. Do I need any kind of trigger to pull opportunities under related list. @Bennie

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will need a trigger on update for opportunities whereby you will check the current month (i.e. Jan, Feb...) and based on the given month you will link the opportunities to that given budget. Obviously you will need a relationship between budget object and opportunity object.

So you will have something like this:

Trigger:

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after update) {
    OpportunityTriggerHandler.assignToBudget(Trigger.new);
}
```

Handler:

```
public class OpportunityTriggerHandler {
    public static void assignToBudget(List<Opportunity> opportunities) {
        List<Opportunity> updateOpportunities = new List<Opportunity>();
        for (Opportunity opportunity : opportunities) {
            //Check if opportunity is closed
            if (opportunity.StageName == 'Closed Won' || opportunity.StageName == 'Closed Lost') {
                //Check month on close date
                Date closeDate = opportunity.CloseDate;
                if (closeDate.month() == 1) {   // 1 is January, 2 is February etc
                    //Link opportunity to budget via field
                    Budget__c budget = [SELECT Id, Budget_Name__c FROM Budget__c WHERE Budget_Name__c =: 'Jan'];
                    if (budget != null) {
                        opportunity.Budget__c = budget.Id;
                        updateOpportunities.add(opportunity);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Update opportunities
        update updateOpportunities;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,this code is working but I have to put budget Month(look field ) into opportunity. so that is showing under budget related list.

Comment: @Russelbaker1 awesome, please mark as correct answer if it helped

Comment: You got me wrong, This code is not working as expected. I have created relation ship between opportunity and budget. So I have to manually update budget field on opportunity so it shows under budget. @Nelson Chisoko

Comment: @Russelbaker1 so are you saying you will effectively do this manually on opportunities? Anyways the trigger is meant to do the update for you when the opportunity is closed. Hence the after update. Anyways if you have found a better solution then awesome :)

Comment: You got me wrong Nelson. I want it  for open opportunities and closed won not closed lost. basically I want to use it as forecasting. So every month budget have related opportunity so we can forecast opportunity amount. I don't want to use standard forecasting of Salesforce.

Comment: @Russelbaker1 oh I see, did you find a solution though

Comment: No, I need your help! @Nelson

Comment: @Russelbaker1 okay, so you have the field on opportunities linking to the budget record right? Now you want to link the opp to the budget if its won so you would change the trigger to check for Closed Won condition. Now whats left would be running the trigger after an opportunity is updated to closed won. Pretty much a trigger is all you need if you have already set up the fields. Try make the required changes using the sample code I have provided and then let me know. Otherwise drop me an email and I can maybe teamviewer and help out if youre stuck at chisokonelson@gmail.com